# Is it possible to rename files in Git and maintain their history if another renamed file had the same name

Tags: git, refactoring, rename

When switching from JavaEE to Spring, the names of the classes need to be changed. This causes a conflict with the Git history.

In Java EE the classes have the names:

FooService and
FooBean

When switching to Spring the classes should be renamed like this:

FooService to FooController and
FooBean to FooService

This causes the following problem. If I rename the name of FooService to FooController its no problem, but if I then rename FooBean to FooService. This refers to the Git history of the JavaEE FooHistory and deletes the history of the first renamed FooController class. Is there a way to maintian the History.

Comment: When you rename a file, Git doesn't delete any history. It may be more difficult to find it.

Comment: No, but also yes. Git itself does not care about "history". Every single commit is effectively a snapshot (except it reuses unchanged/identical objects). That means that any "history view" or anything like that is up to some frontend to compute (sometimes that's the git tool itself). So there's no "magic way" to mark something as "not a move" or "a different thing".

Comment: Maybe try not to rename the two files in the same commit.